# Infinte while loop in C programming language1

Tags: c

I am creating a dice game using C programming language. I ask user to enter a number which must be less than 12 because 5+6=11. 11 is the highest number we get in a dice. After that I randomly generate 2 numbers which are between 1 and 6 because 1 is the smallest and 6 is the highest number on a dice. After that I add the two numbers and keep adding them until it equals to the number user has entered. For example: if user enter 9 we get either 5+4=9 or 6+3=9. The program ends when we get this number. Here is what I have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {

    int totalSought;
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    int count;
    int totalThrows = 2;
    time_t totalTime;

    printf("Game of Dice \n");
    printf("============ \n");

    printf("Enter total sought: ");
    scanf("%d", &totalSought);

    if (totalSought > 11) {
        printf("** Invalid Input! Try Again! **\n");
        while (totalSought > 11) {
                printf("Enter total sought: ");
                scanf("%d", &totalSought);
        }
    }

    srand((unsigned) time(&totalTime));

    while (i < totalThrows) {
        while (j != 7) {
            printf("Result of throw %d %d \n", rand() % 6, j);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

When I run this program I get an infinite loop which looks like this:

```
Result of throw 2 -1218106363
Result of throw 3 -1218106363
Result of throw 1 -1218106363
Result of throw 5 -1218106363
Result of throw 5 -1218106363
Result of throw 2 -1218106363
Result of throw 4 -1218106363
Result of throw 0 -1218106363
Result of throw 5 -1218106363
Result of throw 4 -1218106363
Result of throw 1 -1218106363
```

What I want is something like this:

```
Enter total sought: 5
Result of throw 1: 3 + 1
Result of throw 2: 2 + 6
Result of throw 3: 3 + 2
You got your total in 3 throws!
```

Why am I get an infinite loop?

Comment: Two dice (assuming 6 sided) the highest value can be 12

Comment: while j != 7 <- inside that you never change j's value so j will never be 7 and will never stop looping

Comment: You haven't initialized `j` before you used it.

Comment: You'll have to learn the basics of programming in c first. Look up how to use `printf` properly. Look up how to write a basic loop. Look up how to figure out if `scanf` succeeded or not. What if the user gives 2 invalid inputs? And so on

Comment: int j = 0;, and you should update j in that while (j++).

Comment: @EdHeal yes you are right I missed that!

Comment: `rand() % 6` will result in a number between 0 and 5, not between 1 and 6.

Comment: @mch so if I change rand() % 6 to rand() % 7 I will get a number between 0 and 6. Is there a way to get a number between 1 and 6 not 0.

Comment: `1 + rand() % 6` perhaps

Comment: adding 1 to a number between 0 and 5 will result in a number between 1 and 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. J is not initialised
2. you are not updating the variable J anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You never change your loop terminator value:

```
while (j != 7) {

        printf("Result of throw %d %d \n", rand() % 6, j);
}
```

since `j` never changes, if it enters the loop being "not-7" it will **STAY** "not-7", and the loop will never terminate.

Perhaps you meant to have something more like this:

```
while( j != 7) {
   j= rand() % 6;
   ...
}
```

though that won't ever reach `j=7` either, since you're doing `%6`.

Comment: Technically, since `j` is indeterminate, `j != 7` might appear to be true at first and then change to appearing false, even if it is not updated in the loop.